Understanding the Decomposition of an event determined by random discrete variables in the Markov Property of J.R. Norris
In the statement of the Markov property given in J.R. Norris's $\textit{Markov Chains}$, the property is expressed as follows:
Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a Markov chain with initial distribution $\lambda$ and transition matrix $P$. Then, conditional on $X_m = i$, $(X_{m+n})_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov chain with initial distribution $\delta_i$ and transition matrix $P$, independent of $(X_0, \dots, X_m)$. Specifically, for any event $A$ determined by $X_0, \dots, X_m$, we have
$\mathbb{P}\left( \{X_{m} = i_m, \dots, X_{m+n} = i_{m+n}\} \cap A \mid X_m = i \right) = \delta_{i, i_m} p_{i_m i_{m+1}} \cdots p_{i_{m+n-1} i_{m+n}} \mathbb{P}(A \mid X_m = i).$
My question is about the set $A$ mentioned in this context. From my understanding, this $A$ is said to be "determined by $X_0, \dots, X_m$," which I interpret as meaning $A \in \sigma(X_0, \dots, X_m)$. In the course of the proof, $A$ is decomposed into a countable union of sets of the form $\{X_0 = b_0, \dots, X_m = b_m\}$. However, I do not understand why this decomposition is valid.
Could someone clarify why it is possible to express any $A \in \sigma(X_0, \dots, X_m)$ as such a countable union or why is it sufficient to just look at this kind of events ?

Th sets in a a $\sigma-$ algebra generated by a partition are just all possible unions of the sets in the partition.
